# jQuery slideToggle with logo animation

Tags: jquery-animate, togglebutton, jquery

I am trying to create a drawer from the extreme top of the landing page. I have also setup a logo at the top center edge of the page. So when the user click on the drawer trigger the drawer should open with logo and logo changes its position to `margin-top: some value;` to get the logo vertically and horizontally center of the drawer's bottom edge.

I have this jQuery code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".button").click(function(){
$(".topHidden").slideToggle();
$(".logo").animate({marginTop:'-50px'}, 1000, 'swing');
})
});
</script>
```

I have done the opening part but cannot figure the closing part to get the logo back to its normal position.
Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saadkhaan/t22NL/2/)

Comment: Thank you all, different method, same result. One question though can we stop the logo to go out when the drawer is closing? You may have also noticed a shake/jump effect when drawer opens and closes, how can we fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your jquery code.Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var switchtemp=0;
        $(".button").click(function(){
            $(".topHidden").slideToggle();
            if(switchtemp==0){
            $(".logo").animate({marginTop:'-50px'}, 1000, 'swing');
                switchtemp=1;
            }else{
            $(".logo").animate({marginTop:'0px'}, 1000, 'swing');
                switchtemp=0;
            }
        })
    });
```

Check the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/59Shq/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(".topHidden").slideToggle();
        var margin=$('.logo').css('margin-top');
        if(margin=='0px')
         $(".logo").animate({marginTop:'-50px'}, 1000, 'swing');
        else
         $(".logo").animate({marginTop:'0px'}, 1000, 'swing');   
})
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t22NL/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/t22NL/4/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".button").click(function(){
            $(".topHidden").slideToggle();
            if($('.logo').attr('toggle')== '0'){
                $(".logo").animate({marginTop:'-50px'}, 1000, 'swing');
                $('.logo').attr('toggle','1');
            }else{
                $(".logo").animate({marginTop:'0px'}, 1000, 'swing');
                $('.logo').attr('toggle','0');
            }    
        })
    });
```